# Access Unordered list control id's in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have ul elements in usercontrol like below

```
<u><ul>
  <li id="liMiddle" class="off">
                    <a href="#">One
                    </a>
                    <ul id="One" runat="server">

                </ul>
              </li>
              <li id="liMiddle" class="off">
                <a href="#">Two
                </a>
                <ul id="Two" runat="server">

                </ul>
              </li>
              <li id="liMiddle" class="off">
                <a href="#">Three
                </a>
                <ul id="Three" runat="server">

                </ul>
```

foreach (SPWeb supersubsite in subsites)
                        {
                            int i = 0;
                            HtmlGenericControl li = new  HtmlGenericControl("li");

```
                        CurrentTab.Controls.Add(li);

                        HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                        anchor.Attributes.Add("href", supersubsite.Url);
                        anchor.InnerText = supersubsite.Title;
                        li.Controls.Add(anchor);
                       } </u>
```

Here in each loop Current tab should be changed to corresponding next ul id. How to access it?

I have to generate 'li' elements dynamically under above ul's. So I need to access all the 'ul' id's one by one in the codebehind.

Can anybody tell me the solution?

Comment: Should not you are able to access in code behind ? What I have seen you have Runat="Server" to ul's and set id and it should be accessible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would implement a collection in codebehind where you can add listitems by `presenter/controller` or in `page_load/click_events/..`
And then simple looping in an ASP.NET MVC style..

```
// YourPage.aspx.cs:
private readonly ICollection<string> items = new Collection<string> { "one", "two" };

// YourPage.aspx
<ul>
    <% foreach (var stringItem in this.items) { %>
    <li><%= stringItem %></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I am getting all sites from sharepoint and i have to display those site titles as tabs in menu. for this I have used ul and li structure. Each site may contain subsites. So subsites will be displayed under corresponding ul. At this stage I have to get ul id and need to generate li's. I know how to generate these li's but unable to access the ul id's in foreach.

Comment: i dont really understand, it seems you have a hyrarchy. Mh.. You can do: <%= SomeCodeBehindStringRetunerMethod() %> in your aspx and in this method you generate the ul/li/ul/blabla hyrarchy and simply returns the html directly to the output.

Comment: I have done this in another way. I just keep all ul's under a div and given an ID as 'mainDiv'. 
HtmlGenericControl currenttab = (HtmlGenericControl)mainDiv.FindControl(currentSite);

Here current site it will be same as my ul ID. I will get the current site name from sharepoint site.

Anyhow thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own ListBuilder class with an Add method that takes a custom UserListItem class/struct. Inside of these classes you could use [TagBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.aspx) to create the LI and UL tags using the custom class/struct you built for the UserListItem. You could store a static dictionary of current Lists you're building in that custom ListBuilder class, using an user defined key.

That way if you needed to get at your List, or ListItems dynamically from the code behind, you could just use your ListBuilder and reference them by ID.

Code below is a bit rough, but here's the general idea:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System;

public class UserList
{
    public List<UserListItem> UserListItems = new List<UserListItem>();
    public void Add(UserListItem item)
    {
        UserListItems.Add(item);
    }
}

public class UserListItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class ListBuilder
{
    static Dictionary<string, UserList> userLists = new Dictionary<string, UserList>();
    public ListBuilder(string listId)
    {
        UserList newList = new UserList();
        newList.Add(new UserListItem() { Name = "Item1" });
        newList.Add(new UserListItem() { Name = "Item2" });
        userLists.Add(listId, newList);
    }
    public static UserList GetList(string listId)
    {
        return userLists[listId];
    }
    public static string BuildList(string listId)
    {
        UserList list = userLists[listId];
        TagBuilder listTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("ul");

        list.UserListItems.ForEach(listItem =>
        {
            TagBuilder listItemTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("li") { InnerHtml = listItem.Name };
            listTagBuilder.InnerHtml += listItemTagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        });
        return listTagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }
}
```